# Active Directory Roles - .net core

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-active-directory

I'm currently running .net core inside of IIS on Windows Server on-prem.

I currently have an Active Directory Security Group available, let's call it "group1"

I would like to implement the following logic inside of an MVC Controller

```
if(User.IsInRole("Group1"))
{
    ViewBag.AllowEdit=True
}
```

At a future state inline with Microsoft's plan, would thissolution be hosted inside of App Services of Azure? Would the logic as implemented above be workable for current state solution (i.e. Windows Server on prem) and be future proof without any changes when the Security Groups are replicated to Azure?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to implement this with AAD would be to define the roles in your app's manifest.
Then assign the security groups to the roles. 
And your existing code should then work.

More on defining user roles: https://joonasw.net/view/defining-permissions-and-roles-in-aad

Comment: You can find it in Azure Portal. Go to Azure Active Directory, app registrations, find your app, and then click Manifest

Comment: Okay thank you, I'm operating in a world where Azure doesn't exist yet but will soon.